# HDD is making "crying" noise while shutting down

Tags: hard-drive, noise

I recently bought a 6TB WD Blue HDD and I have noticed that is makes a fairly load "crying" noise while turning off. Here is a recording of the sound: https://sndup.net/8h43
Do you think this should be concerning?

Comment: A decent hard drive does not make noises like this. Can you replace it under its warranty?

Comment: Well I just purchased it new 2 weeks ago, so I should be able to.

Comment: Have you pulled the SMART info off the drive?

Comment: Sound like the famous WD 'dying cow' noise. Return it now!